# How to show ISBN in MS Word Bibliography

Tags: ms-word, bibliography

Actually the question is in the title. I've read here [MS Word Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/create-custom-bibliography-styles) but can't understand where to get a full list of possible fields. I use Russian Word, so the field name should be somthing like `StandartNumber`...

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers). That said, you can access the full list of possible 'fields' by clicking on the 'Show all Bibliograhpy fields' checkbox in the 'Create Source' or 'Edit Source' dialogue box. ISBN data are input into the 'Standard Number' field. However, whether the ISBN will appear in your bibliography depends on which referencing format you use.

Comment: It's a programming question because it relates to xml (xls) configuration of MS Word. I understand where to enter ISBN, but I don't know how to change .xsl config to produce a correct bibliography list. More precisely, how to change the following: `<source type="Book">
        <format>{%CitationPrefix%}{%Author:2|Editor:3|"[Anonymous]"%.}{ %Title|ShortTitle%.{ %Edition:o% ed.}{ Vol %Volume%.}}{ %City%{ (%StateProvince%)}{: %Publisher%{; %Year%}}}{ %Publisher%{; %Year%}}{ %Year%}.{, %CitationPages:p. :с. %}{%CitationSuffix%}</format>
      </source>`

Answer (score 1):

Just insert { %StandardNumber%}